# How to refresh content of PowerApps app field which represent last received email

Tags: powerapps

I've created an app using Microsoft PowerApps which displays the last received email from Office365 mailbox.
I've used this function:

```
Office365Outlook.GetEmails({folderPath:"Inbox/TargetedInboxFolder", fetchOnlyUnread:false, top:1})
```

But the problem is that my app will not automatically update the field for email body `ThisItem.BodyPreview`. I get the body of last received email only when I restart my app.
How to refresh the content of this field when Office365 receive a new email in `folderPath: "Inbox/TargetedInboxFolder"` inbox subfolder, without restarting app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get an auto-refresh, even if you were to create a Flow triggered when a new email is added.

To manually refresh, add a "refresh" button to your app.

Set its `OnSelect` property to:

```
ClearCollect(colLastEmail,
  Office365Outlook.GetEmails(
    {
      folderPath:"Inbox/TargetedInboxFolder",
      fetchOnlyUnread:false, top:1
    }
)
```

Then set your Gallery `Items` property to `colLastEmail`.

Comment: How to set my Gallery Items to colLastEmail. What that means? To select Items from select menu and to type in fx field colLastEmail?

Comment: The "Gallery" is a control (like a Button or Textbox or Label) in PowerApps. Every control has a set of properties you write your functions against. Select the Gallery in question from the "Tree View" then select its `Items` property from the dropdown menu.

Comment: I've already done that, but I've got an error in the formula bar. colLastEmail isn't valid. The identifier isn't recognized.

Comment: That error is usually indiciative of a missing comma, missing parenthesis OR the name of your collection is different than the one I proposed in above. You need to show the code/error if you want us to help further here.

Comment: Thanks. It is actually missing parenthesis error. I've fixed that and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

As SeaDude said, this won't refresh automatically, but you can use a timer on the app. Set the following properties

1. AutoStart: true
2. Repeat: true
3. Duration: set to the time interval between refreshes in milliseconds. So 10 seconds would be 10000.  I would set at least 1 minute (60000) but longer is probably better.
4. Visible: false

Set the OnTimerEnd proprety to collect your email times

```
ClearCollect(colLastEmail,
 Office365Outlook.GetEmails(
   {
     folderPath:"Inbox/TargetedInboxFolder",
     fetchOnlyUnread:false, top:1
   }
)
```

And then set your Gallery to use the ColLastLEmail collection.